# How to Align Text in UITextView Vertically?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios5, uitextview

I have a custom cell with `UITextView` in it. The length of text that I'm loading to this `UITextView` changes from very short to very long. So please, **don't say** "*use a label instead*". I want to keep my cells in same height but to use vertical scrolling of `UITextView` if the text is too long.

I have tried the method [**here**](http://imagineric.ericd.net/2011/03/10/ios-vertical-aligning-text-in-a-uitextview/) but since I am using custom cell initializing in my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` event, the observer didn't work. I tried same method in my cell class under `initWithStyle` function, didn't work either.

What else do you suggest? Or should I work this function in a different way? Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can refer following post, it works for me. http://imagineric.ericd.net/2011/03/10/ios-vertical-aligning-text-in-a-uitextview/

Comment: @RIP, please re-read the 2nd paragraph, I already have shared the same link in my question and declared why I couldn't make it work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your TableView dataSource -

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"myCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    } else { // if there is already a subview, remove it
        while ([[cell.contentView subviews] count] > 0) {
            UIView *labelToClear = [[cell.contentView subviews] objectAtIndex:0];
            [labelToClear removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }


    UITextView *myTextView = // initialise your textView here, including setting its contentOffset

    [cell.contentView addSubview:myTextView];

    return cell;

}
```

Comment: I have been trying but getting empty cell. What do you think of this code? http://pastebin.com/7yKZr2T9

Comment: You haven't told it how big your textView is - it'll have a size of 0x0. You need to do UITextView *myTextView = [[[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:whateverFrame] autorelease]; Also, your contentOffset is working the wrong way - you probably want the x component set to zero, and if you've set the y to the height of the textView, it'll be offset downwards by the height of the textView, so you won't see it anyway! A minus value means the top of the textView will be above the origin.

Comment: not exactly how you said but mostly so, I did it. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Use this -

```
CGSize textSize = [myText sizeWithFont:whateverFont constrainedToSize:myTextViewBox.frame.size lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
```

...then figure out the contentOffset and set it as you add the UITextView to the table.

Comment: thanks but not sure if I got it. should I add the textview dynamically? d'you have any sample code for this?

Answer (score 1):

[Here's a gist](https://gist.github.com/toms972/8330377) I made to show how to vertically align a UITextView